# Embed a view controller inside tab bar programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to dynamically load different **view controllers** on click of tab bar item. But screen appears black not able to see the **view controller** :(

Any help is appreciated. Here is the logic that i am using:

```
class TabBarController : UITabBarController,ENSideMenuDelegate{


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("Inside Tab bar controller")


        tabBar.items?[0].tag = 0
        tabBar.items?[1].tag = 1
        tabBar.items?[2].tag = 2
        tabBar.items?[3].tag = 3
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        //print("Selected Index :\(self.selectedViewController) \(self.selectedIndex)");
        print("Selected Item is \(item.title)  --> \(item.tag)")

        if(  item.tag == 2 ) {
            print("Navigate to ratings view for service provider ")

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
            let destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewX")

            //tabBarController?.viewControllers = [destViewController]
            tabBarController?.setViewControllers([destViewController], animated: true) 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you are removing all view controllers . You have to give all new viewcontrollers during setting

Comment: you are just giving one which is destViewController . . so it will remove all others

Comment: Cant i update of item.tag ==2 alone ?

Comment: You can update but when ever you update, update All not one

Comment: Above code is giving me blank screen, anything needs to be changed ?

Comment: tabBarController?.setViewControllers([destViewController,destViewController1,destViewController2,destViewController3], animated: true), You have to set like this .you have to set all viewcontrollers

Comment: Tried no luck it's still empty ...

Comment: I am able to set view controller by using below code 
                                  
let viewX = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "xxxx") 
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewX)
            self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)

But tab bar is getting missed and not present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146973/discussion-between-badrinath-and-usama-sadiq).